# VueJS the single page template won´t render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I´m starting to learn about Vue. I´ve researched online, and it looks like the most simple one to start with.

At the moment I´ve got two compeonnts:

1. Galleria.vue ==> Where I have a list fetched from data.json.
2. Detail.vue ==> Which is the supposed template to render each item in data.json

Well, When I click in each link and I go to /detail/ID let´s say /detail/1. It won´t render with the information for 1.

https://w9o45.csb.app/

**Galleria**

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="data in data" :key="$route.params.id">
        <router-link :to="{ path: '/detail/' + data.id }">
          {{ data.id }} - {{ data.name }}
        </router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

 

<script>
import data from "../assets/data.json";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: data,
    };
  },
  name: "galleria",
};
</script>
```

**Detail.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>{{ data.name }}</h1>
        <p>{{ data.description }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import data from "../assets/data.json";
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          data: data,
        };
      },
      name: "Detail",
    };
    </script>

**Router JS**
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Galleria from "./components/Galleria.vue";
import Detail from "./components/Detail.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "galleria",
    component: Galleria
  },
  {
    path: "/detail/:data.id",
    name: "Detail",
    component: Detail
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
});

export default router;
```

You can check the online code here.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 way to solved this problem:
first of all you can use this router link:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'detail', query: { id:data.id }}">{{ data.id }} - {{ data.name }}</router-link>
<!-- with query, resulting in `/detail?id=2` -->
```

the second way that can help you is:

```
<router-link :to="'/detail' + data.id">{{ data.id }} - {{ data.name }}</router-link>
```

and the third way is :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: { id: data.id }}">{{ data.id }} - {{ data.name }}</router-link>
```

Comment: Thank you, but not. That works, but it seems like i can´t pass data to /detail/1 so it won´t retrieve the information from ID =1

Comment: maybe you need to change the variable name in v-for. 
v-for="(item,index) in data" :key="index"

Answer (score 0):

As I had an array, I had to select which one using `data[id].name`